# Confusion over `Action` delegate and lambda expressions

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda

```
private void StringAction(string aString) // method to be called
{
    return;
}

private void TestDelegateStatement1() // doesn't work
{
    var stringAction = new System.Action(StringAction("a string"));
    // Error: "Method expected"
}

private void TestDelegateStatement2() // doesn't work
{
    var stringAction = new System.Action(param => StringAction("a string"));
    // Error: "System.Argument doesn't take 1 arguments"

    stringAction();
}

private void TestDelegateStatement3() // this is ok
{
    var stringAction = new System.Action(StringActionCaller);

    stringAction();
}

private void StringActionCaller()
{
    StringAction("a string");
}
```

I don't understand why `TestDelegateStatement3` works but `TestDelegateStatement1` fails. In both cases, `Action` is supplied with a method that takes zero parameters. They may *call* a method that takes a single parameter (`aString`), but that should be irrelevant. They don't take a parameter. Is this just not possible to do with lamda expressions, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you said, Action doesn't take any parameters. 
If you do this:

```
var stringAction = new System.Action(StringAction("a string"));
```

You actually execute the method here, so that is not a method parameter.

if you do this:

```
var stringAction = new System.Action(param => StringAction("a string"));
```

you tell it that your method takes a parameter called `param`, which Action does not.

So the correct way to do this would be:

```
var stringAction = new System.Action( () => StringAction("a string"));
```

or more compact:

```
Action stringAction = () => StringAction("a string");
```

the empty brackets are used to indicate the lambda doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: @Botz: minor correction to your "more compact" statement: `System.Action stringAction = () => StringAction("a string");` (the compiler doesn't have enough info to know that `var` is a `System.Action`).

Answer (score 5):

`Action` delegate is defined as delegate to method, that has no parameters and returns void. In sample 1, you are making 2 mistakes:
1. You are trying to give method, that takes parameter
2. You are invoking the method, and not giving it as a parameter (it should be new Action(methodName)), although, it wouldn't work because of 1.

In sample 2, you are making the same mistake again, your lambda is taking a parameter, you should write it like this:
`new Action(() => StringAction("a string"));`

If you want to create a delegate, that will take a parameter, you should do it like this:
`new Action<string>(myStringParam => StringAction(myStringParam));`

So, in your case, complete code would look like this:

```
private void StringAction(string aString) // method to be called
{
    return;
}

private void TestDelegateStatement1() // now it works
{
    var stringAction = new Action<string>(StringAction);
    //You can call it now:
    stringAction("my string");
}

private void TestDelegateStatement2() // now it works
{
    var stringAction = () => StringAction("a string");
    //Or the same, with a param:
    var stringActionParam = (param) => StringAction(param);

    //You can now call both:
    stringAction();
    stringActionParam("my string");
}

private void TestDelegateStatement3() // this is ok
{
    var stringAction = new System.Action(StringActionCaller);

    stringAction();
}

private void StringActionCaller()
{
    StringAction("a string");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an expert on this, but have you tried this?

```
public void TestDelegateStatement4
{
    var stringAction = () => StringAction("a string");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In C# 2.0, the `Action` delegate is a `void` delegate that doesn't accept parameters.
In later versions, there's the generic `Action<T>` delegate, where T specifies the parameter type.

This should work:

```
var stringAction = new Action<string>(param => StringAction(param));
```

or even better:

```
var stringAction = new Action<string>(StringAction); // using method group conversion
```

then, you can call

```
stringAction("Hello world");
```