# Why Visual Studio IntelliSense is not working here?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Is it not working only for me or for everyone? It's not working everytime I write 'foreach' block inside lambda (dot after `Enumerable`):

```
Action t = ()=>
{
    foreach (var item in Enumerable.)
    {

    }
};
```

Any idea why it's not working in such cases?

I have VS 2010 SP1

update: It's not about `Enumerable`, it's about any object. I can try to write `new object().` and have the same problem.

Comment: Where? I meant to write something like 'Enumerable.Range(1, 10)'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confusion over `Action` delegate and lambda expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382950/confusion-over-action-delegate-and-lambda-expressions)

Comment: The odds that somebody that worked on the IntelliSense parser will answer your question here are very slim.  Post to connect.microsoft.com for better odds.

Comment: Can you please give me direct link? I only found visual studio forum on social.msdn.microsoft.com and can't find anything useful on connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce the bug with VS2010 SP1 and a brand new project:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action t = () =>
        {
            foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
            {
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Delete ".Range(1, 10)" and type "." and you should see Intellisense choices but there are none.  But if you assign the expression to a temporary variable it works as expected.  Follow Hans advice and file a bug report.

Comment: Voted that I can reproduce it.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you type the open and close parantheses for `foreach`, you can get intellisense. For intellisense to work, you need to be typing in front of a white space.

For example:
`foreach` then `()` and then go back into `()` and start typing `var x in` ... no intellisense!
But, `foreach` then `( )` with a space and then go back into `( )` and start typing right after the `(`... now you get intellisense.

This is the behavior with C# settings. Not sure about settings for other languages.

Answer (score 1):

I found that intellisense works for foreach as long as you do not close the brackets. My habit is to type foreach () and then fill the brackets. If I do that intellisense doesn't work, however, if I write foreach ( then the code, then ), then it works.